# What is the purpose of quickfix message store?

Tags: quickfix

What is the purpose of the message store structure in quickfix? I understand that you can log all incoming and outgoing fix messages via the message store interface and quickfix provides multiple implementations like file store etc.

My question is why do you even care about the message store other than logging your fix messages for the record?

Answer (score 6):

You are confusing the MessageStore and the Log, which are two different things.

The **MessageStore** is for internal engine use.  It tracks the current incoming and outgoing message sequence numbers, session start time, and other stuff.  If your app goes down for whatever reason, when it restarts, it uses the MessageStore to resume where it left off with regards to sequence number and whether to reset the session.

The **Log**, however, is just a log.  The engine doesn't really care about it.  It's for the developers.